# Inventory View Screen

Tags: unity, gui

Looking to create an inventory screen in Unity, and trying to think of the best way to do it.

My current line of thinking is having a few rows of squares for inventory items that are drag and droppable onto a paperdoll, a la Diablo.  When dragging and dropping on the items, it would update a 3D model of your current playable object with the items.

The menu itself would be easy enough to do with a simple square and a hierarchy of game objects for the items, each responding to mouse hovering over.

The problem I am trying to figure out is being able to render the 3D model on the side.  Granted, this is a nice to have, and not necessarily a need, but browsing the documentation, the only way I can think of accomplishing this is using a render to texture which requires Unity Pro with a separate camera completely out of bounds of the current space.

Anyone have suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: A better example would be Arx Fatalis: http://oi48.tinypic.com/15rjcat.jpg

Comment: And I'm interested to see an answer for this question too :)

Comment: Yeah, that'd be a good example as well, or EVE Online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will attempt to answer this as best I can.

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to have another camera set up somewhere in your scene, enabling and disabling it when you need to render the inventory.  I applied a different layer to the camera to render separate from my main view.

Hope this helps, there's a pretty good answer over on the Unity Q/A page.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/303620/rendering-3d-objects-on-the-gui.html